# C++ new keyword in inheritance with different types

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, new-operator

I recently started learning OOP. Forgive me if this is a noob question. My question is,
I have thought new keyword is used with only same datatypes such as:

```
char* p = new char; // OR
int* myArr = new int[i] //etc...
```

While studying inheritance and virtual functions I've come across this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Human {
public:
    virtual void className() {
        cout << "Human" << endl;
    }
};
class Asian : public Human {
public:
    void className() {
        cout << "Asian" << endl;
    }
};
int main() {
    Human* h1 = new Asian(); 
    h1->className();
}
```

In the main function, we initialize the pointer with the base class and then there is the derived class after new keyword? What do those 2 datatypes represent, how am I supposed to use them?

Comment: In C++, polymorphism is done through pointers and references.  Usually a pointer or reference to a base class, which could actually refer to a derived class object.  The `virtual` member functions are *dispatched* using the virtual function table of the object (how that happens is a compiler implementation detail, and not programmatically accessible in any portable fashion).

Comment: In c++, you can create an abstract class (Human). Then you created an object Asian (new Asian return a pointer on an Asian). Because of the inheritance you can do the assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in your case, the class `Human` is **accessible** class of `Asian` and

**[$11.2/5 states -](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4618/class.access.base)**

> **If** a base class is **accessible**, one can implicitly convert a pointer to a derived class to a pointer to that base class (4.10, 4.11). [ Note: it follows that members and friends of a class X can implicitly convert an X* to a pointer to a private or protected immediate base class of X. —end note ]

According to the above quoted statement, you *can convert a pointer to the derived class `Asian` to a pointer to the base class `Human`*(which means from `Asian*` to `Human*`), which is what you did when you wrote:

```
Human* h1 = new Asian();
```

In the above statement, on the left hand side we have a pointer named `h1` of type `Human` and on the right hand side by using the keyword `new` we are creating an object of type `Asian` on the heap. But note that using `new` has a **second** effect which is that after the object of type `Asian` is created on the heap then a **pointer** to that object is returned. So essentially,
on the right hand side we get a pointer to `Asian` (Asian*).

Now as i have already explained(quoted) at the beginning of the answer, you can convert a pointer to `Asian` to a pointer to `Human` which is what has happened here.

Now when you wrote:

```
h1->className();
```

There are 3 important facts that you have to consider:

1. `className` is a **virtual function/method**
2. `h1` is a pointer
3. `Asian` inherit `Human` publicly

and according to [virtual function documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.2.0?topic=only-virtual-functions-c)

> a virtual function is a member function you may redefine for other derived classes, and can ensure that the compiler will call the redefined virtual function for an **object of** the corresponding **derived class**, even if you call that function with a **pointer** or reference to a base class of the object.

And so the result is that the derive class' function named `className` is called at **run-time** and we see `Asian` printed on the console.

Answer (score 0):

This is the advantage of using OOP. Suppose you have a car factory and you're making sedan, hatchback and etc. All of them are cars, so they have four wheels, engines, and so on. In order to don't have the same data many times, you can use inheritance. Both the parent and the child class can cast to each other but an example for you to understand is that suppose you have a class that you modify a car. As I didn't specify the type of car, it can be a sedan or a hatchback, instead of having 2 different functions you can have one function that takes the parent object(Car).

`virtual` keyword specifies that the child version of the function should run instead of the parent. So in your example, since we are making an `Asian` object, we will call the child(Asian) version of the `className`. If there was no `virtual` keyword then the parent version would run.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).